# Shortest path in a directed graph with incorporating global path weight

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, directed-graph

Consider a directed edge-weighted graph G = (V,E), with edge-weights in modeling the local relationship between two nodes.

I want to find a shortest path in that graph with additional *global* constraints on the paths, for example formulated in a global path weight. for example a node in path needs to be evaluated with respect to the complete path's history.

Is there an (efficient) algorithm for finding such a path, at best the globally optimal one?

Comment: Well, that's going to depend on the global constraint you have. For example, if your constraint is "Need to walk through all vertices" - this is Hamiltonian Path Problem, which is NP-Complete (no known efficient solution to it). If it's "Need to path through all edges" - that's a much simpler problem (Eulerian path)

Comment: As @amit asked, what are the constraints?